# Combine multiple XSLT templates with similar matches

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have this XSLT below

```
<xsl:template match="word[@italic = 'y']">
        <p>
                <xsl:attribute name="i">yes</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="word[@bold = 'y']">
        <p>
                <xsl:attribute name="b">yes</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="word[@underline = 'y']">
        <p>
                <xsl:attribute name="u">yes</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a way to combine these templates in a single nested block, using a variable that looks something like "italic | bold | underline", while also reflecting the changes in <xsl:attribute name="XXX">? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to combine match patterns is

```
<xsl:template match="word[@italic = 'y'] | word[@bold = 'y'] | word[@underline = 'y']">
```

As for transforming the attributes, can't you just use

```
<xsl:template match="word">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

plus templates for the attributes e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="word/@italic[. = 'y']">
  <xsl:attribute name="i">yes</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

and so on?

Or perhaps

```
<xsl:template match="word/@italic[. = 'y'] | word/@bold[. = 'y'] | word/@underline[. = 'y']">
  <xsl:attribute name="{substring(local-name(), 1, 1)}">yes</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```